# making buttons and handling them

Tags: c++, user-interface, visual-c++, event-handling

How can i make buttons in c++ and handle them.
I am targeting win32.
Till now i have no idea of how to make graphical programs in c++ . I have come from JAVA and therefore have no idea of handling c++ events and building GUI

It will be of great help if you give the links to tutorials or could name the books to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ is merely a language and the framework and operating system services whcih enables you to make use of the services using C++.

Java contains a GUI framework which has implemented across the platform. When you come to a native windows application, you have to rely on mainly two things, Win32 and MFC(a C++ wrapper of Win32 APIs). Win32 provides C based APIs which expose the operating system services.

For your specific questions I can answre like, You can use CreateWindow() Win32 API or CButton::Create() (MFC) to create a button. Also Visual studio provide a really good resource editor where you can manage the controls and make the message handlers.

The APIs are largely classified in to three DLLs

- GDI32.dll - provides APIs for drawing
- User32.dll - provides APIs to creates buttons windows etc.
- Kernel32.dll - provides APIs to use operating system services like file creation, threading, synchronization etc.

As a Java programmer, it would be easy to adopt C# rather than C++. For you C++ might be going back to stone age where you've to hit the stones and make the fire, where in C# you can enjoy the easiness of a matchbox.

I'd suggest you to read following books to learn basic GUI programming under Windows

- [Windows Via C++ - (Win32)](http://rcm.amazon.com/e/cm?lt1=_top&bc1=FFFFFF&IS1=1&bg1=FFFFFF&fc1=000000&lc1=0000FF&t=alwaysbepassi-20&o=1&p=8&l=as4&m=amazon&f=ifr&ref=ss_til&asins=0735624240)
- [Programming Windows with MFC - Jeff Prosise](http://rcm.amazon.com/e/cm?lt1=_blank&bc1=000000&IS2=1&bg1=FFFFFF&fc1=000000&lc1=0000FF&t=alwaysbepassi-20&o=1&p=8&l=as4&m=amazon&f=ifr&ref=ss_til&asins=1572316950)
- [Programming Windows - Charles Petzold](http://rcm.amazon.com/e/cm?lt1=_blank&bc1=000000&IS2=1&bg1=FFFFFF&fc1=000000&lc1=0000FF&t=alwaysbepassi-20&o=1&p=8&l=as4&m=amazon&f=ifr&ref=ss_til&asins=157231995X)

Comment: You're most welcome! BTW. QT is also an option but most of the programmers not really using it unless it's cross platform.

Comment: close the question if you've received the answer. It seems you unmarked the answer of this question

Answer (score 1):

Making UIs is not part of C++ itself : you'll have to use a framework or rely on something else (like MFC in visual c++).

If you want easier way of building a GUI and manage your events, while still keeping your code portable, I suggest having a look at [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) : it's really good quality and delivered with a bunch of well-done examples. (license is LGPL so as long as you link dynamically, you can license your code the way you like).

Answer (score 0):

A very good book to understand win32 api is http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/.